# XUnit - VS2019 - Theory with inlinedata doesn't showing DisplayName in grouping

Tags: visual-studio, xunit

I have a xunit test with Theory and some InlineData. The theory has set the DisplayName property. The test window is showing a test for each InlineData with correct DisplayName but is showing too, a grouping for these tests with namespace, class and method names. How do I set this group to display DisplayName too?

This is the test window

[image: Test window]

This is the code

[image: Code]

Thanks